# How do I use multiple commands to install setx from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, installation

just wondering how I can install `setx` from the command line. I want it to be a silent install with a specified directory. I know that if I type `/?` after the **.exe** it will give me the various options, but how do I combine them? I want to user /c and /t: to only copy files to a directory. How do I combine those?

`setx_setup.exe /?` gives:

> Command line options:
>   /Q -- Quiet modes for package,
>   /T: - Specifies temporary working folder,
>   /C -- Extract files only to the folder when used also with /T,
>   /C: -- Override Install Command defined by author.

If I try:

```
setx_setup.exe /c /t:C:\Program Files\Resource Kit
```

I get:

> Command line option syntax error. Type Command /? for Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this, and it just needs one file, setx.exe, so run that setx setup file once, get that file, put it on a web server and to get it in one command, use wget

or just put that setx.exe file on the computer and you have it. You may even be able to automate that, with sysinternals pstools

and of course make sure that setx.exe is in a location that is already in the PATH, eg c:\windows\system32  or that the PATH is extended to include the directory you put setx.exe

Also, you mean multiple switches not multiple commands.. and for a temporarya directory if you wanted one you wouldn't do the one you mention, and if it had spaces you'd use quotes. But I don't think that gets what you want anyway.

I'm not sure what is quiet about /Q I don't see any switches that make the installation quiet or that automate it.  But you could just use the one file setx.exe then you have it.

Comment: I see what you mean about the switches. But I think just using the .exe file is the way to go for what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> **various options, but how do I combine them?**

I don't know but for most commands or programs multiple command line options can be specified using spaces to separate them thus:

```
setx_setup.exe /c /t:xxx etc
```

Comment: See, I tried that, and it gives me a syntax error. That's why I'm a little confused.

Comment: @Aaron: Can you update your question and cut&paste into it the results of `setx_setup.exe /?` and of the actual command + error message.